# how to change the normal search bar to below image like search bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I just placed one search bar controller with table view. Now its look like normal search bar like this :
[image]

But i need to change this search bar to some thing like below image. :
[image]

Like rounded and search icon should show in last and when i press search, the cancel button should automatically should show.

Now by using code , is it possible to do these changes. Please help me out. How to get like above image.

I am using swift 2.0

Comment: Make custom one :). Use textField instead.

Comment: uitext field?? If i place any image icon for search , then how to get that cancel button when i press search. Can you give some example for this??

Answer (score 0):

1. Take UIView as containerView for your textField, set its background color as you want.
2. Set corner radius to the textField and add some padding to it.

**Corner radius:**

***Swift:***

```
    let textFieldSearchBar = UITextField()
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5.2
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
```

***Objective-c:***

```
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5.2f;
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.borderColor = kTextFieldBorderColor.CGColor;
    textFieldSearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
```

**Left padding:**

***Swift:***

```
    let leftPaddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: paddingWidth, height: 20))
    textFieldSearchBar.leftView = leftPaddingView
    textFieldSearchBar.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

***Objective-c:***

```
    UIView *leftPaddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, paddingWidth, 20)];
    textFieldSearchBar.leftView = leftPaddingView;
    textFieldSearchBar.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

**Right padding:**

***Swift:***

```
    let rightPaddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: paddingWidth, height: 20))
    textFieldSearchBar.rightView = rightPaddingView
    textFieldSearchBar.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

***Objective-c:***

```
    UIView *rightPaddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    textFieldSearchBar.rightView = rightPaddingView;
    textFieldSearchBar.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

3. Now you will need two images, one for Magnifying glass and other for Dismiss/Cross button. Take one button and set these images as background for state Default and Selected. 
   Make outlet of the button and now when you want to show Magnifying glass do [buttonSearch setSelected: NO]; and when Cross button do [buttonSearch setSelected: YES];

***Swift:***

```
buttonSearch.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "magnifyingGlass"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

buttonSearch.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "crossButton"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

//Show magnifying glass image
buttonSearch.selected = false

//Show cross button image
buttonSearch.selected = true
```

I had created custom search bas as below:

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, if possible can you make it for swift 2.0. Because i am starting with swift ios 2.0

Comment: i have tried this code , i am getting some error in `paddingWidth` for left and right padding

Comment: What error you are getting?  Have you tried providing some width as  UIView *leftPaddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];